# How to extract numerical value from Django queryset?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I feel like this is a very simple/stupid question, but for the life of me I can't figure it out.  I'm trying to pull an integer out of a queryset so I can use it with a mathematical operator.  All I can get is the queryset but not the actual number...

```
#models.py
class Contract(models.Model):
    contract_number = models.IntegerField(help_text="This is an auto-calculated value for the sequential number of the contract associated with the account (chronological).", null=True, blank=True)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

---

```
>>> Contract.objects.filter(account="xyz").values_list('contract_number', flat=True)

   <QuerySet [1]>

>>>Max(Contract.objects.filter(account="xyz").values_list('contract_number', flat=True)) + 1

<CombinedExpression: Max(<QuerySet [1]>) + Value(1)>
```

How do I get the actual number out of the queryset so I can use it?

EDIT:  I added more clarity on what I was really trying to do with the Max() function.  There can be multiple objects of the same account name with different account numbers.  I want the maximum number from that list and then I want to add one to it.

Comment: assuming it is always one element, use `.first()` to get it and then increase. otherwise, convert the query set to list and then build a new list

Comment: So you actually want the next `contract_number` for a given `account`? :)

Comment: There can be multiple objects of the same account name with different account numbers.  I want the maximum number from that list and then I want to add one to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another answer based on the revised question:

```
next_contract_number = (
    Contract.objects.filter(account="xyz")  # Filter like usual...
    .aggregate(num=Max("contract_number"))  # Create an aggregation, so we get a dict out . . .
    .get("num")  # ... that we get `num` (the kwarg from above) out; but it may be None, so ...
    or 0  # ... use the fact that `None` is falsy to default to zero . . . 
) + 1  # and add one.
```

Comment: Appreciate all the correct answers but I think this gets to the heart of what I was looking for.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use method `first` and than get the attr `contract_number`

```
Contract.objects.filter(account="xyz").order_by('contract_number').first().contract_number + 1
```

and to exclude the exception if the `Contract` not found you can do it:

```
contract = Contract.objects.filter(account="xyz").order_by('contract_number').first()
contract_number = contract.contract_number + 1 if contract else 1
```

read the doc [querysets first](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#first)

or simple use the `Max` of the [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pl/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet)

```
from django.db.models import Max
max_agg = Contract.objects.filter(account="xyz").aggregate(max_num=Max('contract_number'))
contract_number = max_agg.get('max_num', 1)
```

Comment: This would work too to solve that particular problem.  What I was mostly hazy about is how to pull out the numerical values from the querysets.  Looks like I have to use an attribute like first() or get().  Thanks for your help.

Comment: glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a QuerySet may contain more than one result. If you're sure you only want the first `contract_number`, access it by index 0:

```
number = Contract.objects.filter(account="xyz").values_list('contract_number', flat=True)[0]
```